# Anbox is not starting

Tags: android, anbox

I have Anbox in my system but not able to get a google play app into it to play. When I click on Anbox to open it just says Starting... then closes after a while. Here is what I have in my system.

```
root@terry-ThinkPad-T530:/home/terry# snap info anbox
name:      anbox
summary:   Android in a Box
publisher: Simon Fels (morphis)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/anbox
contact:   https://anbox.io
license:   unset
description: |
  Runtime for Android applications which runs a full Android system
  in a container using Linux namespaces (user, ipc, net, mount) to
  separate the Android system fully from the host.
  
  You can find further details in our documentation at
  https://github.com/anbox/anbox/blob/master/README.md
commands:
  - anbox
  - anbox.android-settings
  - anbox.appmgr
  - anbox.collect-bug-info
  - anbox.shell
services:
  anbox.container-manager: simple, enabled, active
snap-id:      Nr9K6UJaIOD8wHpDEQl16nabFFt9LLEQ
tracking:     latest/beta
refresh-date: today at 12:04 CST
channels:
  latest/stable:    –                                    
  latest/candidate: –                                    
  latest/beta:      4-56c25f1     2020-01-02 (186) 391MB devmode
  latest/edge:      4+gitr6c10125 2020-11-30 (206) 410MB devmode
installed:          4-56c25f1                (186) 391MB devmode
root@terry-ThinkPad-T530:/home/terry# wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geeks-r-us/anbox-playstore-installer/master/install-playstore.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`:

```
binder_linux
ashmem_linux
```

...followed by `sudo update-initramfs -u`.

For me, at first it didn't start but after 1 or 2 reboots it did.

You can also try `export EGL_PLATFORM=x11` before starting anbox, but it seems the environment variable is added automatically so it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that necessary kernel modules are enabled

```
ls -1 /dev/{ashmem,binder}
```

If not, enable it using

```
$ sudo modprobe ashmem_linux
$ sudo modprobe binder_linux
```

also make sure android image is available under /var/lib/anbox/ , if it's not present, download and move it to there ( rename the image file to android.img).
You can download the latest image file from : [Android image file](https://build.anbox.io/android-images/)

and move it using `$ sudo mv ~/Downloads/android_amd64.img /var/lib/anbox/android.img`

After that restart the service `$ sudo service anbox-container-manager restart`

Now you will be able to open the anbox.
[My Anbox setup in Debian 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjBAlFC_s-g)